# Why I cant convert String to Integer

Tags: java, android

I know Its a easy topic but I get error always..I get strings from an xml file that data contains sth like 262626 I tried to convert this string to MB (/1024) form. But it didnot convert to int or long Can some one help me?

Here is what I tested

```
String size = parser.getValue(e, parser.KEY_FileSizeInByte);
Log.i("menuItems",size);

    try {
        int s = Integer.parseInt(size);
        Log.i("s", getString(s));
    }
    catch (Exception e1) {
        Log.i("error", e1.getMessage());
    }
```

I also tested

```
Integer.valueOf(str);
```

here Is the error that I recieve:

```
04-15 23:06:17.652: I/menuItems(6819): 97035
04-15 23:06:17.652: W/ResourceType(6819): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00017b0b
04-15 23:06:17.652: I/error(6819): String resource ID #0x17b0b
04-15 23:06:17.692: I/menuItems(6819): 2957
04-15 23:06:17.692: W/ResourceType(6819): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000b8d
04-15 23:06:17.692: I/error(6819): String resource ID #0xb8d
04-15 23:06:17.692: I/menuItems(6819): 559711
04-15 23:06:17.692: W/ResourceType(6819): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00088a5f
04-15 23:06:17.692: I/error(6819): String resource ID #0x88a5f
04-15 23:06:17.692: I/menuItems(6819): 153651
04-15 23:06:17.692: W/ResourceType(6819): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00025833
04-15 23:06:17.692: I/error(6819): String resource ID #0x25833
04-15 23:06:17.692: I/menuItems(6819): 1733630
04-15 23:06:17.692: W/ResourceType(6819): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x001a73fe
04-15 23:06:17.692: I/error(6819): String resource ID #0x1a73fe
04-15 23:06:17.692: I/menuItems(6819): 532105
04-15 23:06:17.692: W/ResourceType(6819): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00081e89
04-15 23:06:17.692: I/error(6819): String resource ID #0x81e89
04-15 23:06:17.702: I/menuItems(6819): 28817
04-15 23:06:17.702: W/ResourceType(6819): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00007091
04-15 23:06:17.702: I/error(6819): String resource ID #0x7091
04-15 23:06:17.702: I/menuItems(6819): 90787
04-15 23:06:17.702: W/ResourceType(6819): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x000162a3
04-15 23:06:17.702: I/error(6819): String resource ID #0x162a3
04-15 23:06:17.702: I/menuItems(6819): 33556
04-15 23:06:17.702: W/ResourceType(6819): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00008314
04-15 23:06:17.702: I/error(6819): String resource ID #0x8314
04-15 23:06:17.702: I/menuItems(6819): 122145
04-15 23:06:17.702: W/ResourceType(6819): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x0001dd21
04-15 23:06:17.702: I/error(6819): String resource ID #0x1dd21
04-15 23:06:17.702: I/menuItems(6819): 323312
04-15 23:06:17.702: W/ResourceType(6819): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x0004eef0
04-15 23:06:17.702: I/error(6819): String resource ID #0x4eef0
04-15 23:06:17.702: I/menuItems(6819): 532676
04-15 23:06:17.702: W/ResourceType(6819): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x000820c4
04-15 23:06:17.702: I/error(6819): String resource ID #0x820c4
04-15 23:06:17.712: I/menuItems(6819): 49133
04-15 23:06:17.712: W/ResourceType(6819): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x0000bfed
04-15 23:06:17.712: I/error(6819): String resource ID #0xbfed
04-15 23:06:17.712: I/menuItems(6819): 622507
04-15 23:06:17.712: W/ResourceType(6819): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00097fab
04-15 23:06:17.712: I/error(6819): String resource ID #0x97fab
04-15 23:06:17.712: I/menuItems(6819): 57333
04-15 23:06:17.712: W/ResourceType(6819): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x0000dff5
04-15 23:06:17.712: I/error(6819): String resource ID #0xdff5
04-15 23:06:17.712: I/menuItems(6819): 17265
04-15 23:06:17.712: W/ResourceType(6819): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00004371
04-15 23:06:17.712: I/error(6819): String resource ID #0x4371
```

Comment: For one thing, you're currently testing string equality using `!=`. Don't do that. Also, don't just log the *message* of the exception - log the whole exception.

Comment: Thanks for your help..I added this to check If string is empty dont get error for Its convert (at first It was size!=null I changed to size!="" maybe problem fixes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's your logging that's wrong. Here:

```
Log.i("s", getString(s));
```

That's trying to get a *resource* with the given identifier. You just want:

```
Log.i("s", String.valueOf(s));
```